# 54001 stack depth limit exceeded in recursive stable function

Tags: postgresql, functions, errors, postgresql-10, recursive

I have a function which calls itself to resolve a hierarchy. Without any volatility declaration, it gives me the desired result (that means the recursion ends). As a performance optimization, I declared the function as `STABLE` and executed it again. Now it always aborts with the above error, telling me to increase the `max_stack_depth` which sounds like endless recursion to me.

What is happening here?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Did you try and increase the [`max_stack_depth`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-resource.html) parameter? What happened? What is your current value? Have a look at [function volatility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/xfunc-volatility.html) in the official PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: Post a minimal example, including `create table` and `insert` -statements together with the function itself

Comment: @Johnakahot2use It's the default (2 MB). I can increase it to 3 MB with the same error. With 4 MB, the server won't start. I've read all of the documentation but I'm still lost.

Comment: @Lennart I hope I'll find the time…

Comment: Without the function's code this is impossible to answer. But why a function and  not a [recursive common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Writing a function was easier for me.  I'm currently trying to rewrite it as a recursive CTE because `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` only shows `FUNCTION SCAN` instead of the execution plan for the function body. (`auto_explain` with `log_nested_statements` makes no difference.)

Answer (score 2):

A function may not see the same state of the database depending on whether it's `VOLATILE` or not, when this state is changing during the execution of the SQL statement it's called from, either because of the statement itself or because of another transaction if the isolation level is 
Read  Committed.

This is documented in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html

> For functions written in SQL or in any of the standard procedural
>   languages, there is a second important property determined by the
>   volatility category, namely the visibility of any data changes that
>   have been made by the SQL command that is calling the function. A
>   VOLATILE function will see such changes, a STABLE or IMMUTABLE
>   function will not. This behavior is implemented using the snapshotting
>   behavior of MVCC (see Chapter 13): STABLE and IMMUTABLE functions use
>   a snapshot established as of the start of the calling query, whereas
>   VOLATILE functions obtain a fresh snapshot at the start of each query
>   they execute.

If your function reads the database and follows different paths depending on what it reads, it's quite possible that it goes into infinite recursion only when it's not VOLATILE. Looking at the code might be revealing.

Comment: The function (and the outer statement) does not write to the database.

Comment: @xehpuk: nevertheless, a volatile function does not necessarily see the same state as if would if non-volatile. In the read committed isolation level, the state of the data it sees may come from a different transaction that just committed.

Comment: Nothing else is currently running on the database.

Comment: @xehpuk: okay, please show a reproducible example.

Comment: This answer is only relevant if the function is invoked by a data modifying statement, right?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: no, because fresh snapshots are going to be taken by the volatile function whether the invoker query writes or not. I've rephased my first sentence to include read-only queries.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: to be clear I don't believe that this report is correct with the additional constraints added by the OP in the comments. I think the difference of behavior between stable and non-stable function in a read-only setup must be explained by a  difference of database state when testing.